# Remove all groups with more than N observations

Tags: python, pandas

If a value occurs more than two times in a column I want to drop every row that it occurs in.

The input df would look like:

```
Name   Num
  X     1
  X     2
  Y     3
  Y     4
  X     5
```

The output df would look like:

```
Name   Num
  Y     3
  Y     4
```

I know it is possible to remove duplicates, but that only works if I want to remove the first or last duplicate that is found, not the nth duplicate.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Name'], drop='third')
```

This code is completely wrong but it helps explain what I was trying to do.

Comment: What if there are four values, do you want to drop 3 and 4 or just 3?

Comment: @ScottBoston I want to drop anything after 2. So 3, 4 ,5, etc.

Comment: @ScottBoston updated question, If a value occurs more than two times I want to drop every instance of it.

Comment: you have two great answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `head`

```
df.groupby('Name').head(2)
Out[375]: 
  Name  Num
0    X    1
1    X    2
2    Y    3
3    Y    4
```

---

```
s=df.groupby('Name').size()<=2
df.loc[df.Name.isin(s[s].index)]
Out[380]: 
  Name  Num
2    Y    3
3    Y    4
```

Comment: updated question, If a value occurs more than two times I want to drop every row that it is in.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and filter all values less like `2`:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Name').cumcount() < 3]
print (df1)
  Name  Num
0    X    1
1    X    2
2    Y    3
3    Y    4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('Name').cumcount())
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT

Filter by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Name')['Num'].transform('size') < 3]
print (df1)
  Name  Num
2    Y    3
3    Y    4
```

Comment: updated question, If a value occurs more than two times I want to drop every row that it is in.